# How do I create tags like stack overflow's in Rails with acts-as-taggable-on gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using acts-as-taggable-on gem to create tags. Tags are created fine. However, I want to go a step further and implement them like stackoverflow . Anybody done something similar. Anyone know of a tutorial that would walk me through it ?

Comment: You saw this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elSfdUnn5jc

Comment: That part is already done. I am only stuck with the real-time tag creation in the form. Like the same experience as adding skills in Linkedin

Comment: You need something like this https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: let me know if you need a help to implement this. I have something like that here.

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi I definitely do need help. Can you share with me your example ?

Comment: How do I implement it in this line:   = f.text_area :tag_list, label: "Tags (optional)", help: raw("All tags .<br>We do this to ensure..."), input_html:{data:{placeholder: "Enter tags", saved: f.object.tags.map{|t|{id: t.name, name:t.name}}.to_json}, url: autocomplete_tags_path}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120920/discussion-between-moussa-sarr-and-breno-perucchi).